# Keep Bluetooth connection alive and persistent when iOS app moved to background

Tags: ios, background, bluetooth, connection, persistence

I have an iOS project where I'm retrieving heart rate data from a standard Bluetooth sensor continuously and sending it to a web server. I want this to work when the app moves to background and when the user locks the screen. I've tried various approaches: checking off the bluetooth settings in background mode section of the project settings, playing music in the background. I don't have to submit this to the App Store, so what are some (possibly underhanded) ways to keep a persistent Bluetooth connection in the background?

Comment: Does your peripheral support `notify` for the characteristics? If so, use that.  If not then you are probably stuck - If you aren't going to the app store and aren't too concerned about battery life you can disable locking in your app

Comment: Hey Paul, it does support `notify`, and we already use `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic`. It doesn't seem to help though.

Comment: I wish someone answered this I am stuck on the same thing. I am using didUpdateValueForCharacteristic as well and it won't wake the app up from terminated to notify. It does when the app is in the task switcher but once I swipe it up and kill it, the notifications stop in the app.